# Postgres group by empty string question to include empty string in output

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

I have following table in Postgres

```
| phone | group   | spec   |
| 1     | 1       | 'Lock' |
| 1     | 2       | 'Full' |
| 1     | 3       | 'Face' | 
| 2     | 1       | 'Lock' | 
| 2     | 3       | 'Face' | 
| 3     | 2       | 'Scan' |
```

Tried this

```
SELECT phone, string_agg(spec, ', ')
FROM mytable
GROUP BY phone;
```

Need this ouput for each phone where there is empty string for missing group.

```
| phone | spec 
| 1     | Lock, Full, Face
| 2     | Lock, '' , Face
| 3     | '', Scan ,''
```

Comment: Why 3 members in the list  for 4 distinct values?

Comment: because there are three distinct groups, phone 2 doesn't have group '2' value and phone 3 doesn't have groups '1' and '3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `CTE` which returns all possible combinations of `phone` and `group` and a `left join` to the table so you can `group by phone`:

```
with cte as (
  select * 
  from (
    select distinct phone from mytable   
  ) m cross join (
    select distinct "group" from mytable  
  ) g 
)  
select c.phone, string_agg(coalesce(t.spec, ''''''), ',') spec
from cte c left join mytable t
on t.phone = c.phone and t."group" = c."group"
group by c.phone
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qNDNvjENii5TtWoyDs9Jd3/1).
Results:

```
| phone | spec           |
| ----- | -------------- |
| 1     | Lock,Full,Face |
| 2     | Lock,'',Face   |
| 3     | '',Scan,''     |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select phone,
       (max(case when group = 1 then spec else '''''' end) || ', ' ||
        max(case when group = 2 then spec else '''''' end) || ', ' ||
        max(case when group = 3 then spec else '''''' end) 
       ) as specs
from mytable t
group by phone;
```

Alternatively, you can general all the groups using `generate_series()` and then aggregation:

```
select p.phone,
       string_agg(coalesce(t.spec, ''''''), ', ') as specs
from (select distinct phone from mytable) p cross join
     generate_series(1, 3, 1) gs(grp) left join
     mytable t
     on t.phone = p.phone and t.group = gs.grp
group by p.phone
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a `self - (RIGHT/LEFT)JOIN` with all three distinct groups (which's stated within the subquery just after `RIGHT JOIN` keywords ) and a correlated query for your table :

```
WITH mytable1 AS
(
SELECT distinct t1.phone, t2."group", 
      ( SELECT spec FROM mytable WHERE phone = t1.phone AND "group"=t2."group" )
  FROM mytable t1
  RIGHT JOIN ( SELECT distinct "group" FROM mytable ) t2
    ON t2."group" = coalesce(t2."group",t1."group")
)
SELECT phone, string_agg(coalesce(spec,''''''), ', ') as spec
  FROM mytable1
 GROUP BY phone;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8c53cf17d1f26377a6c7f73454622fd9)</kbd>